# Getting menu links: correct chain of API functions

Tags: 7, routes

In my module, I need to create sort of a menu block consisting of certain menu items collected from various menus, and flattened into one level.

I'm not sure about the correct chain of the Menu API functions to call. My first attempt was as follows:

```
function _MYMODULE_block_view(){
  $html = '';

  $menu_link = menu_link_get_preferred('node/287');
  $html .= theme('menu_link', $menu_link);
  dpm($menu_link);
  return $html;
}
```

but it raises an error about several #attributes missing, so I guess this is not the right kind of object to get markup from. The API [docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/group/menu/7) don't really help in understanding what kind of objects/parameters are returned/expected by functions, hence the question.

**Edit:**

Having given what Drupal complained about, the code now is as follows:

```
function _MYMODULE_block_view(){
  global $language;
  $langcode = $language->language;

  $html = '';

  $paths = array(
    'node/287',
    'node/3',
  );

  foreach($paths as $path){
    $translations = i18n_get_path_translations($path);
    if(!empty($translations[$langcode])){
      $i18n_path = $translations[$langcode]['href'];

      $menu_link = menu_link_get_preferred($i18n_path);
      $link = array(
        '#theme' => 'link',
        '#text' => $menu_link['link_title'],
        '#path' => $path,
        '#options' => array('attributes' => array('title' => $menu_link['link_title'])),
        '#below' => NULL,
        '#title' => $menu_link['link_title'],
        '#href' => $path,
        '#attributes' => array(),
        '#localized_options' => array(),
        '#prefix' => '<li>',
        '#suffix' => '</li>'
      );
      $html .= theme('menu_link', array('element' => $link));
    }
  }

  return "<ul>$html</ul>";
}
```

It does not spit out errors but... should I really trust it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `menu_link_get_preferred()` I'm guessing Drupal 7 here...

Theme functions have changed, and parameters now need to be named in an associative array passed to the theme function. So per the [`theme_menu_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) docs:

```
$html .= theme('menu_link', $menu_link);
```

becomes

```
$html .= theme('menu_link', array('element' => $menu_link));
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know, but this code gives me error as previously. Please see my edited question with updated code.

Comment: Next edit: error-free, but is it Drupal-way?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that as far as I can tell...you could use `theme_item_list()` to avoid having to prefix and suffix the element with list tags, but that's a small improvement

Comment: I don't like `theme_item_list()` for it has hardcoded wrapper and class :) but that's another story. Thanks Clive for pointing me in the right direction.